# Autenticação manual de uma campo da tabela no Framework Laravel 5.3

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, laravel-5, lógica

Estou começando agora com o `Framewok Laravel 5.3.`, no entanto quado crio com `artisan o make:auth` ele automaticamente cria as `views`, `model`, e `controllers` referente a ***Login de acesso***. Só que adicionei um campo na `tables users` chamado `status` do tipo `boolean`. Preciso fazer uma verificação se esse `status` esta como `true (1)` ou  `false (0)`.

Como eu faria esse procedimento. Então, pensei assim, crio um objeto exemplo:

```
$data = Auth::user();
```

*e faria a verificação com o `if`*

```
if($data->status === true){
```

*ele entraria na sessão*

```
} else {
```

*ele retornaria para o login com uma messagem dizendo que o status dele esta atualmente desativado.*

```
}
```

Porque se não tiver essa verificação, o usuário simplesmente ira entrar no painel de administração. Espero que tenha entendido.

Comment: Esse campo `status` vai ser mudado a seu critério, certo? É só mais um passo de verificação até o login ser bem sucedido?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie um [`middleware`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware) e configure o seu projeto nas rotas de administração seja conferido se pode ou não, siga o passo a passo:

No console digite:

> `php artisan make:middleware CheckStatus`

será criado na pasta `app/Http/Middleware` um arquivo `CheckStatus.php` edite da seguinte forma:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CheckStatus
{        
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (\Auth::user()->status == 1) 
        {
            return redirect('home');
        }    
        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

para registrar esse [`middleware`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware) criado `CheckStatus` entre `app/Http/Kernel.php` em `$routeMiddleware` adicione uma chave (**auth.status**) da seguinte forma:

```php
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,

    'auth.status' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckStatus::class,
];
```

depois adicione na sua rota(s) (`Route`):

*Em um rota:*

```php
Route::get('admin/', function () 
{

})->middleware('auth.status');
```

*Em um grupo de rotas:*

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth.status'], function () {
    Route::get('/admin/change', function ()    
    {

    });

    Route::get('admin/profile', function () 
    {

    });
});
```

Pode também ser adicionado direto no `Controller`:

```php
class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth.status');

    }
}
```

Nesse [link tem a tradução](http://laravel.artesaos.org/docs/master/middleware) feito pelos *Artesões* grupo [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel).

***Referencias:***

- [Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware)
- [HTTP Middleware](http://laravel.artesaos.org/docs/master/middleware)

Comment: Veja ai a minha rota ai em cima, pois ainda esta passando sem verificar o campo status.

Comment: Olha a minha rota . Mesmo assim ainda esta passando mesmo com o meu campo da tabela sendo 0 . o certo era para ele passa se for == 1 não é?
Route::group(['url' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'auth.status', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'Admin'], function () {
    Route::get('admin', function () {
        return view('Painel.admin_template');
    });
    Route::get('profile', 'ProfileController@profile');
    Route::post('profile', 'ProfileController@update_avatar');
    Route::resource('artigo', 'ArtigoController');
    
   
});

Comment: @NatanMelo status == 1 é isso que você fez. Porque no código esta true. Passe o código do seu middleware

Comment: Então, mais eu fiz tudo certo como vc descreveu, mesmo assim ele não verifica o meu status. Pq se no meus status o usuario esta como 0
e mesmo assim ele esta logando.

Comment: Desculpe eu sou iniciante no laravel e não estou entendendo muito bem o que esta acontecendo. Eu dei uma lida o manual em pt-br que vc sugeriu, mais mesmo assim não deu certo.

Comment: @NatanMelo todo o inicio não é fácil, principalmente com `framework` que tem muitos versionamentos e tudo mais. Você precisa exatamente do que? eu entendi que deseja bloquear algumas rotas que são dos tipo administrador é isso? relate em poucas palavras por favor novamente! acredito também que falte detalhes no código para solucionar de imediato seu problema, mas, vale lembrar que é bom começar com Laravel do inicio Autenticação e Autorização que são coisas diferentes são meio chato de aprender no Laravel.

Comment: Entendi. quando entro na url /register ele entra no form. de login. quando cadastra ele e redirecionado para a area admins. Preciso que depois do cadastro de login, ele faça uma verificação se o campo status da tabela users está como 1. se não tiver como 1 ele volte para a tela de login com a mensagem que o usuario ainda esta desativado. Digo isso para que a área adminis. fique segua. Se não fazer isso, qualquer um que registrar tera acesso a área administrativa. Fico grato por estar me ajudando.

Comment: @NatanMelo esse padrão que é passado para o usuário, não server muito (ou melhor tem que mudar bastante coisa) para ser um elo para parte administrativa, porque, nesse modelo que vem por padrão é como se qualquer usuário pudesse se cadastrar e acredito que o seu objetivo seja outro. Ele te oferece exemplo de como logar no site, de como cadastrar usuário no site, mas, eu por exemplo só uso como referencia, eu crio baseado na documentação o meu tipo de autenticação e autorização mediante a esses códigos exemplos. Então é complicado porque você é iniciante e não sei como ajudar mais ...

Comment: Ok muito obg, pelo feed back.